# Using ionice on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

My cronjob consumes 100% cpu even using ionice.
Did I do something wrong?

```
for db in ${databases}; do
  ionice -c 3 nice -19 mysqldump -h localhost...
  wait
done
```

PS. Amazon Linux

Comment: Is anything else vying for CPU during that time? Is this causing any performance problems?

Comment: only when I run this mysqldump

Comment: Is the load going above 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting nice and ionice priorities for mysqldump process which does not really consumes much, it only sends commands to mysqld process. You should lower priorities for mysqld or (much harder but much better way) setup a Mysql-slave server and make backups from it.